# How to exclude records from table in a query?

Tags: mysql

I have a table named BDS.cursuri, which has the columns `"id_cadru", "tip_curs"`. Example of records:

I have tried this:

```
id_cadru    tip_curs   
   8         modul I
   5         modul II
   8         modul III
   6         modul III      

SELECT BDS.cursuri.ID_CADRU FROM BDS.cursuri,
    (SELECT * FROM BDS.cursuri where TIP_CURS = "modul I") AS cu_m1
    where BDS.cursuri.ID_CADRU NOT IN (cu_m1.ID_CADRU);
```

I expect the output 5 and 6, meaning the records that don't have `tip_curs='modul I'`, because the person with `id_cadru=8` has already `tip_curs='modul I'`, but I also get the output 8. How can I solve this? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You you should use the NOT IN in subquery not in join

```
SELECT BDS.cursuri.ID_CADRU 
FROM BDS.cursuri 
    where BDS.cursuri.ID_CADRU NOT IN (
      SELECT id  FROM BDS.cursuri where TIP_CURS = "modul I"
    );
```

or use a not exist clause for the same subquery

Answer (score 0):

We can try using an `EXISTS` clause here:

```
SELECT t1.id_cadru, t1.tip_curs
FROM BDS.cursuri t1
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM BDS.cursuri t2
                  WHERE t1.id_cadru = t2.id_cadru AND t2.tip_curs = 'model I');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with below query

```
SELECT BDS.cursuri.ID_CADRU 
FROM BDS.cursuri 
    where BDS.cursuri.ID_CADRU != (
      SELECT ID_CADRU FROM BDS.cursuri where TIP_CURS = "modul I"
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This,

It will return the `id_cadru 5,6,8` with `modul II`,`modul III`.

> select id_cadru,tip_curs from BDS.cursuri where id_cadru in (select
>   distinct(id_cadru) from BDS.cursuri where tip_curs in ('modul
>   II','modul III')

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using following query

> SELECT * 
>     FROM BDS.cursuri
>     WHERE id_cadru NOT IN (SELECT id_cadru FROM BDS.cursuri WHERE `tip_curs` = 'modul I')
>     AND `tip_curs` NOT IN ('modul I')